# Intellij IDEA gradle debug plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

Using IDEA 2017.1(ue); I like to know how I can debug a gradle plugin. I've setup a very simple gradle project (https://github.com/tkvw/gradle-plugin-debug). The project references one plugin org.gradle.hello-world.

My questions are:

1) Where can I set a breakpoint on the helloworld plugin? Normally I lookup my classes/sources using search anywhere in IDEA, but it doesn't find the class/sources. Idea seems to ignore the buildscript dependencies of the gradle build in it's sources lookup path?. (I tried the "old" buildscript block + apply as well)

2) How do I setup -Dorg.gradle.debug=true on the run configuration? If I specify it like this: the task simply runs and doesn't wait for a debugger to be attached. 
[image: Run configuration]
From the command prompt the command

```
gradlew -Dorg.gradle.debug=true helloworld
```

does run and wait for a debugger to connect.